# How can i save a value in the textbox to a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I want to store the value given in the text box in a variable. I am beginner to javascript. Please help me out. Here s my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Days of Journey: <input type="text" id="doj" name="daysofjourney">
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="dayscounter()">

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var travel = document.getElementById("doj").value;

function dayscounter() {
    var days;
    for(days = 1; days <= travel; days++) {
        document.write(days);
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value

Comment: Checked. But cant get my answer. I have used a loop to find out whether it s working or not. My output was none.If i replace the value of travel by  any number i am getting output. Thats wat my problem is, the variable value is not stored. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You nearly had it already...

```
function dayscounter() {
    var travel = document.getElementById("doj").value;
    var days;
    for(days=1;days<=travel;days++)
    {
        document.write(days);
    }
}
```

The problem was, that your first assignment of the variable travel is made as soon as the HTML code is loaded. The user can't have made an input yet at that time, thus the variable stays empty. If you include `document.getElementById("doj").value` inside the function, you will get the value at that specific time you launch the function.

Answer (score 1):

Just parse value to int

```
var travel = +(document.getElementById("doj").value;);
```

Comment: Now how can I use this "travel" variable and print in in the html body (append it )

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'value' attribute of an text input to set it's value like:

`<input type="text" id="textid" value="value content" />`

and you can do your function like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function dayscounter()
{   
    var travel = document.getElementById("doj").value;
    var days;
    var result = "";

    for (days = 1; days <= parseInt(travel); ++days)
    {
        document.getElementById("result").value += " " + days;
    }
}
</script>


Days of Journey:
<input type="text" id="doj" name="daysofjourney" />
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="dayscounter()" />

<p>
    <input type="text" id="result" />
</p>
```